# How do I trigger a change event on radio buttons in react-testing-library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm in the process of moving over to react-testing-library, and have no idea how to trigger this event and get the results of the changes.

I've tried using the `fireEvent` function to trigger the change, and then tried the `rerender` function, but I can't seem to get it to work.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

const options = {
  DoTheThing: 'DoTheThing',
  DoOtherThing: 'DoOtherThing',
};

function App() {
  const [action, setAction] = useState(options.DoTheThing);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <form>
          <fieldset>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="radio1"
                value={options.DoTheThing}
                checked={action === options.DoTheThing}
                onChange={event => setAction(event.target.value)}
              />
              First
            </label>

            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="radio1"
                value={options.DoOtherThing}
                checked={action === options.DoOtherThing}
                onChange={event => setAction(event.target.value)}
              />
              Second
            </label>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from 'react-testing-library';
import App from './App';

afterEach(cleanup);

it('should change the value ', () => {
  const {getByLabelText, rerender } = render(<App/>);
  const second = getByLabelText(/Second/);

  fireEvent.change(second);
  rerender(<App/>);

  expect(document.forms[0].elements.radio1.value).toEqual("DoOtherThing");

});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**

As people pointed out my original solution was wrong.

Nowadays I suggest you use [`userEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro) for better-simulating user interactions.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";

test("radio", () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();
  render(
    <form>
      <label>
        First <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="first" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Second <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="second" />
      </label>
    </form>
  )

  await user.click(screen.getByLabelText("Second"));
});
```

---

First, you don't have to call `rerender`. You use `rerender` only when you want the component to receive different props. See [link](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#rerender).

Whenever you call `fireEvent` the component will render like it would in your normal app.

It's correct to fire a `change` event, but you must pass a second parameter with the event data.

This example works:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";

test("radio", () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(
    <form>
      <label>
         First <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="first" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Second <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="second" />
      </label>
    </form>
  );

  const radio = getByLabelText('First')
  fireEvent.change(radio, { target: { value: "second" } });
  expect(radio.value).toBe('second')
});
```

Comment: I originally sent a mock event, but then saw some [presumably] older info showing that was unnecessary. I'd only added the rerender because I couldn't see the change itself.

Comment: I remember why I had re-render. Ultimately, what I want to test is the appearance of a particular set of inputs after the value has changed. My first step was being able to assert that the change to the radio happened. I was using `waitForElement`, but it just times out and throws. Should I create a new question for that?

Comment: `waitForElement` is useful if something asynchronous happens e.g. you're waiting for a `fetch` response. In this case, you should not need to wait for anything because the update happens immediately.

When `waitForElement` fails I try to use `wait` instead. If even that doesn't work the problem is usually somewhere else. Usually, my component doesn't update at all.

Comment: This isn't how radio buttons work though. Their value is fixed. Only their checked state changes.

Comment: All this code is doing is changing the value of the first radio button to "second". now you just have 2 radio buttons with the value "second" but neither of them are checked. Also it doesn't cause the react onChange handler to be invoked, so it's not really useful

Comment: Agreed, this is not a correct example even if it is an acceptable answer, I have lost hours around this misled by this path.

Answer (score 34):

if you have a label like with Radio Component of Material-ui, you could use:

```
const labelRadio: HTMLInputElement = getByLabelText('Label of Radio');
expect(labelRadio.checked).toEqual(false);
fireEvent.click(labelRadio);
expect(androidRadio.checked).toEqual(true);
```

or you can add https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom matchers and check it in this way:

```
expect(getByLabelText('Label of Radio')).not.toBeChecked();
fireEvent.click(labelRadio);
expect(getByLabelText('Label of Radio')).toBeChecked();
```

Answer (score 6):

As of May 2020 using React 16.13 and react-testing-library 10.0, the accepted answer does not work (the test itself passes but doesn't actually do anything meaningful).

I can't find any reference to radio buttons in the documentation for react-testing-library or even React itself. However, here's an example (using Typescript) that works properly as far as I can tell.

```
import React from "react";
class State {
    radioValue: string = "one"
}
export default class RadioTest extends React.Component<{}, State>
{
    state: State = new State();

    radioClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>) => {
        this.setState({ radioValue: event.currentTarget.value });
    }

    render() {
        return (<>
            <label>
                One
                <input type="radio" name="radio" onClick={this.radioClick}
                    value="one" onChange={() => {}}
                    checked={this.state.radioValue === "one"} />
            </label>
            <label>
                Two
                <input type="radio" name="radio" onClick={this.radioClick}
                    value="two" onChange={() => {}}
                    checked={this.state.radioValue === "two"} />
            </label>
            <div>current value={this.state.radioValue}</div>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({radioValue:"one"})}>Click</button>
        </>);
    }
}

test("radiotest", () => {
    const { getByLabelText, queryByText, getByText } = render(<RadioTest />);
    const one = getByLabelText('One') as HTMLInputElement
    const two = getByLabelText('Two') as HTMLInputElement
    expect(one).toBeChecked();
    expect(two).not.toBeChecked();
    expect(queryByText("current value=one")).toBeTruthy();
    fireEvent.click(two);
    expect(one).not.toBeChecked();
    expect(two).toBeChecked();
    expect(queryByText("current value=two")).toBeTruthy();
    fireEvent.click(getByText("Click"))
    expect(one).toBeChecked();
    expect(two).not.toBeChecked();
    expect(queryByText("current value=one")).toBeTruthy();
});
```

React onChange handlers will work in the browser but not with react-testing-library because they don't fire when you call fireEvent.change()

The dummy onChange handlers are required to avoid a React warning: "*If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`*". You can't use  defaultChecked though, because it stops you setting the state in code (i.e. clicking the button at the bottom doesn't update the radio)

So on the whole, it looks like React wants you to use `onChange` but react-testing-library only works with `onClick`, so this is a bit of a fudge.

Comment: This was the solution for our issue.  .change does not trigger the behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @andy's answer, this should test two radios effectly:

```
  it('should render successfully', async () => {
    render(
      <YourRadioGroup />
    );

    expect(screen.getByText('option 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(screen.getByText('option 2')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('should change checked option', () => {
    render(
      <YourRadioGroup />
    );

    const secondRadio = screen.getByLabelText('option 2');
    fireEvent.click(secondRadio);
    expect(secondRadio).toBeChecked();

    const firstRadio = screen.getByLabelText('option 1');
    fireEvent.click(firstRadio);
    expect(firstRadio).toBeChecked();
    expect(secondRadio).not.toBeChecked();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use like mentioned below solution for RadioGroup. It will work for RTL.

```
render(component);
const fieldset = screen.getByLabelText(/other applicable cards/i);
expect(fieldset.checked).toEqual(false);
fireEvent.click(fieldset, { target: { value: '2' } });
expect(fieldset.value).toEqual('2');
```

Can use for manage multiple radio click event.

```
  render(component);
  const fieldset = screen.getByLabelText(/other applicable cards/i);
  expect(fieldset.checked).toEqual(false);
  fireEvent.click(fieldset, { target: { value: '2' } });
  expect(fieldset.value).toEqual('2');
  const fieldset1 = screen.getByLabelText(/original amex platinum/i);
  expect(fieldset1.checked).toEqual(false);
  fireEvent.click(fieldset1, { target: { value: '1' } });
  expect(fieldset1.value).toEqual('1');
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (working with the radio buttons, not the radio groups):

```
// some code here to make sure the screen has finished rendering, and I have all radio buttons in the DOM (I am expecting 5 containers):
await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getAllByTestId('some-slow-loading-container')).toHaveLength(5))

// get all "true" labeled radio buttons by test id (or by role + name or whatever):
const allTrueLabelRadioButtons = screen.getAllByTestId('true-label-radio-button');

// loop over the array of HTML elements found:
for (const trueLabelRadioButton of allTrueLabelRadioButtons) {
   // using fireEvent instead of userEvent because of some bugs with the components library I am stuck with. Usually I use userEvent:
   fireEvent.click(trueLabelRadioButton)
}

// check whatever you are expecting to happen after all radio buttons are set to "true".
//...
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this from react-testing-library docs, "render" should work fine. Agree with @Gpx

```
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'your_value_goes_here' } })
expect(input.value).toBe('expected_value')
```

Answer (score -1):

I've also had this work for me:

```
test('Does stuff', async () => {
// ... test prep ...

const formEl = screen.getByTestId('form_test_id')

// You can use screen.getByLabelText here instead of DOM queries 
// if you've got a nicely laid out form
const defaultInput = formEl.querySelector('input[value="default_value"]')
const newValueInput = formEl.querySelector('input[value="new_value"]')

// Confirm your baseline
expect(defaultInput.checked).toEqual(true)
expect(newValueInput.checked).toEqual(false)

// Fire the change event
await act(async () => {
fireEvent.change(newValueInput, { target: { checked: true } }) 
// To trigger any onChange listeners
fireEvent.blur(newValueInput)
})

// Confirm expected form state(s)
expect(defaultInput.checked).toEqual(false)
expect(newValueInput.checked).toEqual(true)

})
```