# Testing a radio button click event resulting in "checked"

Tags: react-testing-library

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701224/how-do-i-trigger-a-change-event-on-radio-buttons-in-react-testing-library) where the following example is given:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "react-testing-library";
test("radio", () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(
    <form>
      <label>
         First <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="first" id="firstRadioId" />
      </label>
      <label>
        Second <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="second" />
      </label>
    </form>
  );
  const radio = getByLabelText('First')
  fireEvent.change(radio, { target: { value: "second" } });
  expect(radio.value).toBe('second')
});
```

But that feels kind of odd since it's not the result of a click that's being tested. But rather it's directly setting the value to a certain string.
However, the click event does not work:

```
  // ...
  const radio = getByLabelText('First')
  const radioSecond = getByLabelText('Second')
  fireEvent.click(radioSecond);
  expect(radio.value).toBe('second');
  // ...
```

The thing that I don't get is why `document.getElementById('firstRadioId').checked` is returning false. In the browser it does, as can be seen in the example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-saha-xt0j7

On the index page you see that radio.checked returns true. But in the test it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-saha-xt0j7), you have the following:

```
  it("changes the value based on the radio buttons", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(tree);
    const radio = getByText(/My label/i);

    fireEvent.click(radio);
    // why is this false?
    expect(radio).toHaveProperty("checked", true);
  });
```

If you debug `radio`, you'll find that your query returned a label, which won't have the attribute `checked`:

```
<label
  for="myRadioButton1"
>
  <input
    id="myRadioButton1"
    name="myRadioButtonGroup"
    type="radio"
  />
  My label
</label>
```

If you want to check something's `checked` attribute, you should get the radio button using `getByRole`:

```
  it("changes the value based on the radio buttons", () => {
    const { getByRole } = render(tree);
    const radio = getByRole("radio", { name: /My label/i });
    fireEvent.click(radio);
    expect(radio).toHaveProperty("checked", true);
  });
```

To anyone reading this, consider using `debug` (preferrably using [screen.debug()](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screendebug)) when you are unsure why something isn't working.