# Paste test in cypress in reactjs project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

Any ideas how to simulate **Paste** action in Cypress in a bundle with React?

My test should check value right after paste action.

I found few [solutions](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1123) based on DOM manipulation because as the authors say it pastes changes **directly** to DOM input field and then envoke **change** event.

My tried `cy.get(selector).invoke('val', 'copy-pasted text').trigger('change');`

These solutions dont work as expected because React manipulates the DOM it-self hence the "pasting" by suggested ways pushes changes directly to input values and violates React workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think this code could help you:

add to commands:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("paste", { prevSubject: true }, (selector, pastePayload) => {
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event
  cy.wrap(selector).then($destination => {
    const pasteEvent = Object.assign(new Event("paste", { bubbles: true, cancelable: true }), {
      clipboardData: {
        getData: () => pastePayload
      }
    });
    $destination[0].dispatchEvent(pasteEvent);
  });
});
```

usage:

```
cy.getByTestId("some-input-test-id").paste('some text');
```

The main difference between this and other examples from the internet is that your plugin could have problems catching what was "really" paste. So ie callback `onItemsPaste` in [blueprint](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/multi-select) would not catch anything. [Original](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2386#issuecomment-613374266) version.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! worked smoothly for me

Answer (score 1):

The [React Testing Library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) will fire the change event in a React app.

Ref [How do I trigger a change event on radio buttons in react-testing-library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54705810/4716245)

I wrapped it in a Cypress custom command for convenience.
Seems the element wants to be focused first.

```js
import { fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";

Cypress.Commands.add('fireEvent', {prevSubject: true}, (element, event, value) => {
  element.focus()
  fireEvent[event](element[0], { target: { value } });
})
...

it('fires change event', () => {
  cy.get(selector).fireEvent('change', 'copy-pasted text');
  /* 
    Test react re-render effects here with re-tryable commands,
    e.g should(), not expect()
  */
});
```

**Is this a Paste test?**

There is a [paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event), so perhaps 'change' is not really testing the scenario. Is there a difference between typing and pasting? Will circle back to this.

BTW I use

```js
cy.get(selector).focus().clear().type('copy-pasted text');
```

without a problem.

The only caveat, as above, subsequent commands must be ***retryable*** to give React time to process (or add `cy.wait(100)`).

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesnt not reproduce *paste* action, because it doesnt use *navigator.clipboard.readText()* :( but as i read it's a know issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2386

Comment: Cheers, I wondered what the criteria was (you missed that out of the question). I saw a work-around for `navigator.clipboard` somewhere, it's been a few days but I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I have the copied text to the clipboard. Now, I want to paste that text to the textbox of my application.

Answer (score 0):

```js
cy.window().its('navigator.clipboard')
    .invoke('readText').then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
```

Should do the trick.